# Float right in rtl css

Tags: css, css-float, right-to-left

Now I have this set up in css

```
.one-half{
width: 305px;   
margin-right: 30px;
float: right;
} 
.feat-cat .last-col{
margin-right: 0;
}

.feat-cat{
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 30px;
direction: rtl;
}
```

when i do this way

(.feat-cat .last-col) disappear as you can see
[image]
**How do I do it correctly??**

this is the site that i work on it 
http://hossamyehia.com/wordpress/

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask? It just looks like a post to your website

Answer (score 7):

For RTL layouts there are several properties you need to flip.

These include, but are not limited to:

- background
- background-position
- border
- border-radius
- clear
- cursor
- direction
- float
- left/right
- margin
- padding
- text-align
- text-indent

It's your margin-right which is causing the problems.

Change these to margin-left and it will work.