# bootstrap css file not let direction go to rtl in PHP MVC

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I has problem with bootstrap css file in php mvc everything work fine but the direction not go to right to left and bootstrap css work fine but when i delete the bootstrap css direction go to right to left because i want to let page go to right to left or left to right depend on language

Comment: why is this tagged as php? is there relevance?

Comment: yes cuz maybe after render app since i am working on php mvc i dont know why only the problem with bootstrap css maybe cuz of render @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: well, the pending edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21151740 is attempting to remove it. You can reject it if you feel it is php related. If it is related, you're going to have to show relevance and the code for all this, given it is php code, and relevant html/css.

Comment: i am guessing maybe from something code cuz others css file doesnt have this issue so i mention php cuz maybe they know or they had this problem before but what code i need to insert in post since the language i get from cookie depend on language i make RTL or LTR but this not work with bootstrap maybe i have something wrong in my render so if someone with exp i can show the code for rendering app

Answer (score 0):

You probably see this effect because Bootstrap is applying styles that only work in a LTR context. [It looks like](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24807) there is currently no support for RTL in Bootstrap, though it sounds like it is planned for Bootstrap 4. There are a handful of 3rd party support tools for this, but I cannot recommend any as I have not tried them.

Comment: But why in normal project i mean without doing mvc work fine RTL i am set RTL in html tag

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your code. As seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017098/float-right-in-rtl-css/16017506#16017506), there are a handful of properties that may need to be fixed when switching between LTR and RTL. Styles applied to the right or left of elements stay to the right or left of elements whether you are in LTR or RTL